# applying datepicker to multiple instances of the same webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap date range picker. In a single page i need to use it in multiple places with each date picker having its own minimum and maximum date range enabled. Please find the code demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypgBGi10vVPe89Nq6rP7?p=preview)

js code:

```
var cb = function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    console.log("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ", label = " + label + "]");
}

var optionSet1 = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    minDate: '08/01/2014',
    maxDate: '12/31/2017',
    dateLimit: {
        days: 60
    },
    showDropdowns: true,
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 1,
    timePicker12Hour: true,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: 'left',
    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
    applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'btn-small',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        cancelLabel: 'Clear',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
    }
};

$('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);

$('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("show event fired");
});
$('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("hide event fired");
});
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
});
$('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("cancel event fired");
});
```

html code:

```
Select SIM Date Range : <input id="reportrange" class="simDateRange">
<br><br><br>

Select Phone Date Range: <input id="reportrange" class="phoneDateRange">
```

I want to reuse the same js code to show daterange picker in multiple places of my webpage and i need to set minimum and maximum date range for each date range.Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in angular we use `directives` to reuse elements. With v1.6 we use components also. But as per your requirement

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ygTgeAG21K0t1LLMttnx?p=preview) with changes

Just mention unique `ng-model` names of inputs in index.html to get their values
and to have different start dates, you must mention different ids/classes and have a single function to construct `optionSet1` and pass this to the function with class name then set in that function

```
function constructOptions(minDate, maxDate){
   // this is just an idea
   // here construct the optionSet
   // then call cb with desired element
}

function cb(element){
    // logic
}
```

**Here is my updated** [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FgudpF3V700U2oKKyzy3?p=preview)

Comment: Thankyou, each daterange picker has its own minumum and maximum date which i will get dynamically. How to assign that to the individual date picker so that only the dates fall on that range should be enabled.Currently i have assigned static dates to minDate and maxDate attributes.
And another question was i have to know which date picker is selected, how can i know that. Based on the date selected from SIM Date Range/Phone Date Range i have to do some processing at backend.Please advice. @Mr_Perfect

Comment: I am doing that. Wait

Comment: Now see the changes in the same plunker

Comment: @Mr-Perfect - Thankyou,when user click on sim Date Range Picker , i have to hit my spring controller which takes one parameter of type which is used to call corresponding backend logic to get the min and max date for SIM/Phone date range which user has selected.I need to pass some value like simDate for SIM Date range picker when user click on that date picker and phoneDate for Phone Date Range picker.

Comment: In my local application, i use to call $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() .., $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function().in my html page else datepicker was not showing on the page( and remaining js code i placed in separate js file). But with your code, datepicker is not showing even when i replaced #reportrange with .reportrange. Please advice.. there are loading issues i guess, but no errors are displayed in the browser console

Comment: Are you using angular? only jquery? If it is angular, better go for this https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker

Comment: I'm using angularjs and bootstrap in my application, can i achieve that functionality with the example i shared here http://plnkr.co/edit/ypgBGi10vVPe89Nq6rP7?p=preview . As i already spent enough time on  getting this . .@Mr_perfect

Comment: Hey,my plunk is working but the intial values are not showing. Just make sure that

Comment: Try to have initial values same as we set before. We can set it by moment but takes time to get time and format the date as we shown in input

Comment: Here, It is very difficult to answer all your questions in a single plunker. if it works accept/reject the answer and ask question

Comment: And there is a method `callBackend()` use this for your backend calls by sending appropriate value. No need to have different controllers for different date pickers. Respond as quick as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145597/discussion-between-mr-perfect-and-participantjava).