# how to know from which component the input is passed when i have multiple components of same type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When two dates are selected and click on submit in daterange picker,callback function is called.
I have two daterange pickers(SIM date range and Phone Date Range), when user selects date range from 1st daterange picker and submit how to know in the callback function that user has selected dates from 1st date picker and viceversa.
When user submit the dates, i should know from which date picker the user has selected.
Please find the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OnvUEBzhYWsaGipUNLwC?p=preview

js code:

```
 var cb = function(start, end) {
   $('.reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
alert("in set-dates.js , callback function");
 }

 function constructOptions(element) {
   var optionSet1 = {
    startDate: element.startDate,
    endDate: element.endDate,
     minDate: element.minimumDate,
     maxDate: element.maximimDate,
     dateLimit: {
       days: 60
     },
     showDropdowns: true,
     showWeekNumbers: true,
     timePicker: false,
     timePickerIncrement: 1,
     timePicker12Hour: true,
     ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
     },
     opens: 'left',
     buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
     applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
     cancelClass: 'btn-small',
     format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
     separator: ' to ',
     locale: {
       applyLabel: 'Submit',
       cancelLabel: 'Clear',
       fromLabel: 'From',
       toLabel: 'To',
       customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
       daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
       monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
       firstDay: 1
     }
   };
    $(element.elem).daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);
 }


// here are the elements 
 var elements = [{
   elem: $('.simDateRange'),
   minDate: '08/01/2014',
   maxDate: '12/31/2017',
   startDate: moment().subtract(10, 'days'),
   endDate: moment().subtract(5, 'days'),

 }, {
   elem: $('.phoneDateRange'),
   minDate: '08/05/2014',
   maxDate: '11/31/2017',
   startDate: moment().subtract(50, 'days'),
   endDate: moment().subtract(3, 'days')
 }];

elements.forEach(function(element){
  constructOptions(element);
})
```

html:

```
 Select SIM Date Range :
  <input class="reportrange simDateRange" ng-model="simDate" />
  Select Phone Date Range:
  <input class="reportrange phoneDateRange" ng-model="phoneDate" />
```

Comment: I have answered here to the question right https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290570/6554634

Comment: @Mr_Perfect - +1.  Glad you r online. I'm facing issues to know from which daterange picker the user selected the date..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class name from the element

```
$(this.element)[0].className
```

It is better to have id for your input.

I have fork your plunker and add in id for the input. [Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7wyfNhgckuSFyrhsq2Ua?p=preview)

Comment: Can u pls update the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OnvUEBzhYWsaGipUNLwC?p=preview. I could not able to get the class name in the callback function.

Comment: In your callback function,  `alert("in set-dates.js , callback function");` change to 
 `alert($(this.element)[0].className);`

Comment: Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/NYRzOl2mb1oZaapBD7EB?p=preview . It has other information also instead of only class name. I want class name so that i can write an if(condition) to call corresponding logic for the selected daterange picker.

Comment: I can't update your demo. As I mentioned earlier, use id in your input. `<input id="simDateRange" class="reportrange simDateRange" ng-model="simDate" />`  then `alert($(this.element)[0].id);`

Comment: I am doing the same in my plunker @participantjava. But we have a small problem with that. Setting intial values

Comment: @participantjava I have updated my answer with working plunker.